# How to filter results in datagridview combobox based on combobox outside datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to use the datagridview to input multiple data into sql, but I am having a hard time to bind the datagridview combobox to show items based on the selected item in the combobox (supplier), I can't even bind my sql in the datagridview combobox, sorry for being a noob, but I am trying to finish  this project. the code below is the code that I use, it is based on individual comboboxes and textbox and not binded on datagridview.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Inventory.Properties;

namespace Inventory
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MEDIXPC197;Initial Catalog=Inventory;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand();

        private void label15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'inventoryDataSet.dbTrans' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.dbTransTableAdapter.Fill(this.inventoryDataSet.dbTrans);
            cc();
            cc2();
            cc3();
        }

        public void cc()
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Department from tbldept";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["Department"].ToString());
                comboBox2.Items.Add(dr["Department"].ToString());
            }


            conn.Close();
        }

        public void cc2()
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select distinct Supplier from tblmaster";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add(dr["Supplier"].ToString());
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        public void cc3()
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Transaction] from [tbltransac]";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox4.Items.Add(dr["Transaction"].ToString());
            }
            conn.Close();
        }


        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbldept where Department = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbldept where Department = '" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblmaster where Supplier = '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Da.Fill(dt);

            comboBox5.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox5.Items.Add(dr["ProductCode"].ToString());
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from [tbltransac] where [Transaction] = '" + comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblmaster where ProductCode = '" + comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                textBox3.Text = dr["Description"].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = dr["UM"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = dr["UP"].ToString();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

EDIT:
Picture below shows my design, I want to filter what will show in Item Code combobox inside the datagridview based on the Supplier combobox
[PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ4pH.jpg)

Comment: You are going to have some problems with this approach. First, looking at the posted picture, the “itemCode” combo box column in the grid… “usually” would contain all the same items for each row. However, from your comment…  _”I want to filter what will show in Item Code combobox inside the datagridview based on the Supplier combobox”_ … this “implies” that each “combo box” on each row MAY have different items. The problem in this may be best described with a scenario...

Comment: Let’s say there are “multiple” rows in the grid and the user “changes” the external “Supplier” combo box value. After the user changes the “Supplier” value…  “WHICH” row’s “Item Code combo box” should get changed??? I am guessing from the picture, you should add the “Supplier” combo box to the grid. That way if the “Supplier” for that row changes… you will know which “Item Code” values to add to the “Item Code” combo box.

Comment: This will mean that you will need to wire up the `CellValueChanged` event to check if the supplier is changed. If it is changed, then the code will need to fill that rows “Item Code” combo box with the appropriate values. I hope that makes sense.